# Refreshing tableView in JavaFx after closing dialog

Tags: javafx

I have two layouts in JavaFX app. The first one contains table view whereas the second one is a simple dialog to input data. The problem is that I want to refresh data after closing the dialog. Now I have a button on the first layout which refreshes data:

```
data.removeAll(data);
loadDataToTable();
```

But I don't want to invoke methods shown above with the button but automatically right after closing the dialog. I don't know how to make this, let's say, connection between those controllers.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `Dialog`, if I am not wrong must be a new Stage ! Let us consider the new Stage to be `modifyStage`. We can call the `onSetCloseRequest` of the new Stage and put your code in it.

```
modifyStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent paramT) {
        data.removeAll(data);
        loadDataToTable();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have this dialog as a new Stage. Your 'setonCloseRequest' is exactly what I looked for. Thanks